# WebRequest sometimes does not return

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity's webrequest. It works most of the times and I get a response with the data but sometimes it does not return the data at all. Is it because I am running it in a loop?
The reason I am running it in a loop is because multiple URLs are getting called.

I thought of adding a while loop since if the data is not received, it will call the request again but won't that degrade my performance?
What is the suitable solution here?

Should I use a while loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < urls.Count; i++) {
            UnityWebRequest webReq = UnityWebRequest.Get (urls[i]);
            yield return webReq.SendWebRequest ();
            var json = webReq.downloadHandler.text;

            if (uwr.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError) {
            Debug.LogFormat ("Error downloading file");
        } else {
            Debug.Log("Success!");
        }
}
```

Comment: Also, most of the time now, i do not receive the right data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Dispose UnityWebRequest or use a using block for it.
I would suggest to maybe try hitting the URL's one by one to check if the URL's are always returning data.
Other than this I would suggest to wrap the WebRequest logic to a coroutine and wait for it to finish inside the loop.